# Typescript: Using a tuple as index type

Tags: typescript, recursion, tuples, pluck, index-signature

Given is a tuple of some keys like `["a", "b", "c"]` and a nested object with those keys as properties `{a: {b: {c: number}}}`. How do you recursively use the members of the tuple as index in typescript?

A implementation without proper typing:

```
function recursivePluck(ob: any, tuple: any[]): any {
  for (let index of tuple) {
    ob = ob[index]
  }
  return ob
}
```

How do you type the above code?

I have tried the following

```
type RecursivePluck<
  Tuple extends string[], 
  Ob extends {[key in string]: any}, 
  TupleWithoutFirst extends SliceStartQuantity<Tuple, 1> = SliceStartQuantity<Tuple, 1>
>

= TupleWithoutFirst extends [] ? Ob[Tuple[0]] : RecursivePluck<TupleWithoutFirst, Ob[Tuple[0]]>
```

But this errors `Type alias 'RecursivePluck' circularly references itself.`

> Note that `SliceStartQuantity` is from `typescript-tuple` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-tuple))

Comment: @AluanHaddad The problem is that I dont know where to start. I dont know how to Iterate over a tuple of arbitrary length and use its members as consecutive indexes.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Im sorry if I was imprecise. Though I dont understand what you mean with `I thought you were asking how to write the type signature of the function not have to implement it.`. 

Thanks a lot for the recursion tip. It gave me a starting point. I tried solving the problem using recusrion, but I got into some issues regarding `circularly references`. Have I missunderstood your directions? I put my attempt into the querstion. Would you be so kind an have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution, it covers type safety of the argument and of the return type:

```
type Unshift<A, T extends Array<any>> 
= ((a: A, ...b: T) => any) extends ((...result: infer Result) => any) ? Result : never;
type Shift<T extends Array<any>> 
= ((...a: T) => any) extends ((a: any, ...result: infer Result) => any) ? Result : never;

type Revert
  <T extends Array<any>
  , Result extends Array<any> = []
  , First extends T[keyof T] = T[0]
  , Rest extends Array<any> = Shift<T>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Rest['length'] extends 0 ? Unshift<First, Result> : Revert<Rest, Unshift<First, Result>> 
}[0]

// this was done to avoid infinite processing the type by TS
type Level = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
type NextLevel<X extends Level> = 
  X extends 0
  ? 1
  : X extends 1
  ? 2
  : X extends 2
  ? 3
  : X extends 3
  ? 4
  : X extends 4
  ? 5
  : never

// this type will give us possible path type for the object
type RecursivePath<Obj extends object, Result extends any[] = [], Lv extends Level = 0> = {
  [K in keyof Obj]: 
    Lv extends never
    ? Result
    : Obj[K] extends object 
    ? (Result['length'] extends 0 ? never : Revert<Result>) | RecursivePath<Obj[K], Unshift<K, Result>, NextLevel<Lv>>
    : Revert<Result> | Revert<Unshift<K,Result>>
}[keyof Obj]

// checks if type is working
type Test = RecursivePath<{a: {b: {c: string}, d: string}}>
type Test2 = RecursivePath<{a: {b: {c: {e: string}}, d: string}}>

// this type will give as value type at given path
type RecursivePathValue<Obj, Path extends any> = 
{
  [K in keyof Path]: 
    Path extends any[]
    ? Path[K] extends keyof Obj 
    ? Path['length'] extends 1 
    ? Obj[Path[K]]
    : RecursivePathValue<Obj[Path[K]], Shift<Path>>
    : never
    : never
}[number]

// checks if type is working
type Test3 = RecursivePathValue<{a: {b: {c: string}, d: string}},['a', 'b']>
type Test4 = RecursivePathValue<{a: {b: {c: {e: string}}, d: string}}, ['a','d']>

// finnaly the function
function recursivePluck<Obj extends object, Path extends RecursivePath<Obj>>(ob: Obj, tuple: Path): RecursivePathValue<Obj, Path> {
  // inside I just fallback to any
  let result: any = ob;
  for (let index of tuple as any[]) {
    result = result[index]
  }
  return result;
}
const a = recursivePluck({a: {b: {c: {d: 'value'}}}}, ['a','b']) // ok
const b = recursivePluck({a: {b: {c: {d: 'value'}}}}, ['a','e']) // error
const c = recursivePluck({a: {b: {c: {d: 'value'}}}}, ['a','b','e']) // error
const d = recursivePluck({a: {b: {c: {d: 'value'}}}}, ['a','b','c']) // ok
const e = recursivePluck({a: {b: {c: {d: 'value'}}}}, ['a','b','c', 'd']) // ok
```

[The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgZwBYEsBmwA8BBANFAFSggA9gI4ATBKbAJzoEMRNG4QA%20DqAWACgAvFAAUwxgC5a%20AHSyARpIIBKKAO5sQK0uSo1Rs6XQgIArgBtgklHDQQ6UAErHzwFWqgaVAfkfOLUSTgIADc7AG5%20UEgoAGVUDEwibQpqWgZmVnYuXkERYQMJQjd1di0yFL0xSQ0ZWSNTCysbO18G11USzSgfJzaAqCDQugi%20SPBoJyHgfigoROJy3TSmFg0OGah8XpcFnVT6FczOVSgAbQBdDfwAMRQ6BGBdisJTgGsIEAB7NEJzk4JTgAGS58WZbYyPZJLA4ZNYnOLoLAEbJCADeG1OAGkoNYoO8vj8COdJL1gKcAORmCgAc2ASHJfyhqUB3VgiHiWFu92A4La3BJITsWFJ%20HgyERmC5D15Lmy-AAvkCQWNogAZQVmE4sgA%20UAAjFBdQAmQ1QADMpoALKaAKwq6AAOW06tCZkwAA0nksXRAzNwhBtPUyaICNj49RtJEHFqkI6DWUbI1Bo3saIn4z4zUmU88sxmoJbs17UoX83b44FBXR%20PbfABjEz3FChAAKjDpmAA8nIAFbFmifXsQOs81o7YMedgXE4XfCq4L9qA%20zVCQH%20qDo%20NYnFwPEfb5Qbs94k5WazeeLwZ2DazHp%20abx2aSI9YxkxgdDkens8%20YTbCwUlScC0vSb6plALI%20Fe9gClMmD-sAHAqLqTgNk2rbtkgXa9q%20orshKmIyhYHD4E6ZDLpg85cDe-STEK8H3twKFVlgYocpghEIdRfCKviB5HsqfBRNABAQicqGNggzYQG2HaooUqIKBudaSA8dDWNS8r4JQqnAOpwHyvK6xCeMhAQiaQgSehMmYZg8mSIpDkqRuEC6fpmlaVAOlQGpGmGcZtZWVJGF0gAaowZgmBA2E9vgslIIucIBnwm6zNuuJ8T88UnjR8WJVOIJnqy8WvoumWHr2363lAJWUjSdIMouBo0T4L4lZi5yFWeApocFNlhRFUUxac7WdfgCIJPF3FFZWQw0bN148accAmAAtnIdiCcJZkPBalnDpJ0nxeFkXRfZG5Kaizm%20QZ2luX5WkUow5L4OScgMsZ22iQ81r7b1R2YSdQ3nY5ykOa5Pl6Q9d2Q%205hn4E9L3kpQH01nwAD06NQGg1hwBFIBQHS0BoCYcAjignxwPwJNk8AFO7kY-2tpFdavDFi6Dj2w6jnlE5BQDHZHlwwiDs%20vb4MAJhgFSkjxUoPWHSFSBA9FR5xZh3CpVAmM7lJlDQAAklAPYmA82MRWYciMKzhOfJOIAbFSjz1C41TsCcg4jLMaCfPYwhOzu%20skFAB6S9L0CMDQGgXCoWuzC7-hCAnZLWEHXXyhsRiS3QDP3iMGd8HWlNm4wJyM4rMks68wgg5dzmot55LBINEDkoZ8NnOSz24G9DIqDrnyvPwReII8chlwd1ktlXNcKXXDmN83p1t%203CNd0jrfnP3WN2HQvvD8Xjx1hPTOVyYrOzw588bovLcrx3iM9%209Peb9vxAMPvheH15J8V9P5-V1rk5Bekgm533bp5R%20vce51j7trLGg8D6j2IL-KeM8gFgxvqApeUV76QPXk-JGsDXooy3vAkOrwgA)

Comment: Sorry for no explanation, but I need to go sleep :D. If you need it I can cover it tomorrow

Comment: This is absolutely awesome, thanks **alot** for your time. I really appreciate it.

Thanks, the comments are sufficient explaination :).